# python multiple decorators change argument

Tags: python, arguments, decorator

i try to understand python decorator, but i show this strange behaviour
In this piece of code I have try to use multiple decorator for alter my function workflow

This is the code

```
def myfilter(f):
    def decorator(data):
        if data['num'] %2 == 0:
            data['num'] = 90
        f(data)

    return decorator

def myduplicator(f):
    def decorator(data):
        print 'duplicator data', data
        f(data)
        print 'duplicator data', data
        f(data)
    return decorator

@myduplicator
@myfilter
def testone(data):
    print data

for i in range(3):
    testone({'num': i})
```

And this is the answer

```
duplicator data {'num': 0}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 90}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 1}
{'num': 1}
duplicator data {'num': 1}
{'num': 1}
duplicator data {'num': 2}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 90}
{'num': 90}
```

why the second call of decorator in myduplicator has change data result

```
print 'duplicator data', data
f(data)
```

The result that I want is

```
duplicator data {'num': 0}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 0}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 1}
{'num': 1}
duplicator data {'num': 1}
{'num': 1}
duplicator data {'num': 2}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 2}
{'num': 90}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what the decorator does. It mutates the dict. And since you use the same dict twice, it has already been modified by the first call.

Answer (score 0):

After applying these two decorators, your `testone` functions is equivalent to following:

```
def testone(data):
    print 'duplicator data', data
    if data['num'] %2 == 0:
        data['num'] = 90
    print(data)
    print 'duplicator data', data
    if data['num'] %2 == 0:
        data['num'] = 90
    print(data)
```

You can see here that the same `data` is being modified both times.

Now if I run this function it gives similar results:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     testone({'num': i})
duplicator data {'num': 0}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 90}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 1}
{'num': 1}
duplicator data {'num': 1}
{'num': 1}
duplicator data {'num': 2}
{'num': 90}
duplicator data {'num': 90}
{'num': 90}
```

Comment: And if I want to apply the follows decorator twice what I can do ? I must do a swallow copy structure/dict ?